# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'navigation' is marked as required

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to start with react native, i'm making a login screen and register, but i'm receiving the warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `navigation` is marked as required
>   in `Login`, but its value is `undefined`.

My login component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { StatusBar, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

import api from '../../services/api';

import {
    Container,
    Logo,
    Input,
    ErrorMessage,
    Button,
    ButtonText,
    SignUpLink,
    SignUpLinkText,
} from './styles';

export default class Login extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };

    static propTypes = {
        navigation: PropTypes.shape({
          navigate: PropTypes.func,
          dispatch: PropTypes.func,
        }).isRequired,
    };

    state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', navigation: {navigate: '', dispatch: ''} };


    handleEmailChange = (email) => {
        this.setState({ email });
    };

    handlePasswordChange = (password) => {
        this.setState({ password })
    };

    handleCreateAccountPress = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Registrar');
    };

    handleSignInPress = async () => {
        if(this.state.email.length === 0 || this.state.password.length === 0){
            this.setState({error: 'Necessário preencher email e senha para entrar!'}, () => false);
        } else {
            try {
                const response = await api.post('/sessions', {
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password
                });

                await AsyncStorage.setItem('@FabricaDeMonstroApp:token', response.data.token);

                const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [
                        NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Main'}),
                    ],
                });

                this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);

            } catch (_err){
                this.setState({error: 'Houve um problema ao entrar. Verifique suas credenciais'});
            }
        }
    };


    render(){
        return(
            <Container>
                <StatusBar hidden />

                <Logo source={require('../../images/logo.png')} resizeMode="contain" />
                <Input
                    placeholder="Endereço de e-mail"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={this.handleEmailChange}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}    
                />
                <Input
                    placeholder="Senha"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    secureTextEntry    
                />

                {this.state.error.length !== 0 && <ErrorMessage>{this.state.error}</ErrorMessage>}
                <Button onPress={this.handleSignInPress}>
                    <ButtonText>Entrar</ButtonText>
                </Button>

                <SignUpLink onPress={this.handleCreateAccountPress}>
                    <SignUpLinkText>Criar conta grátis</SignUpLinkText>
                </SignUpLink>

            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

In my routes.js i write this stackNavigation:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

import Login from './pages/login'
import Registrar from './pages/registrar'
import Main from './pages/main'

const Routes = createStackNavigator({
    Login,
    Registrar,
    Main,
});

export default createAppContainer(Routes);
```

Comment: Do you want to go to Main page?

Answer (score 0):

Although your component is registered in the StackNavigator, you need to pass it down the navigation props to make it work properly.

For that, you can add the HOC withNavigation in your login component:

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions, withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Login extends React.Component {
// ...
}

export default withNavigation(Login);
```

Comment: WithNavigation is used when the navigation element cannot be delivered directly to the component or if you do not want to deliver it in the case of children who are deeply nested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to the mains from the `login page`, you can call the page navigation command. When you navigate to the `main page`, the `main page` is activated above the `login page`.

**Login.js**

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
```

To reset the state to a point where the active screen was Login Screen but have it stacked on top of a Main screen, you would do the following:

```js
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Main' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```